# Is there a way to remove from the final artifact any unused dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I know that, thanks to maven dependency plugin, I can analyze and see unused dependencies.

However, my idea would be to define a master pom with already defined dependencies (no dependency management) so to have the child pom cleaner.

This has a price: the final artifact is gigantic as it also brings inside dependencies that it does not need.
Is there a way to automatically remove unused dependencies while still having them in the pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You could, of course, write your own plugin that controls what is packaged into the final artifact. But even if you would, Maven would resolve all the dependencies at the beginning of the build, download them all if not present and build a huge compile classpath.

Just stick with dependencyManagement.